# App Engine, PIL and overlaying text

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to overlay some text over an image on GAE. Now they expose the PIL library it should not be problem.

Here's what I have. It works, but I can't help think I should be writing directly to the background image rather than creating a separate overlay image and then merging.

Can I use [Image.frombuffer](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) or something, I've given it a go but I'm just not getting it...

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.api import files

def compose(key):

    # create new image
    text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (800,600), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_img)
    draw.text((0, 0), 'HELLO TEXT', font=ImageFont.load_default())

    # no write access on GAE
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    text_img.save(output, format="png")
    text_layer = output.getvalue()
    output.close()

    # read background image
    blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(key)
    background = images.Image(blob_reader.read())

    # merge
    merged = images.composite([(background, 0, 0, 1.0, images.TOP_LEFT), 
                               (text_layer, 0, 0, 1.0, images.TOP_LEFT)], 
                               800, 600)

    # save
    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='image/png')
    with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(merged)
    files.finalize(file_name)
```

Comment: Plz, how could you install PIL on googleappengine? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `[Image.open][1]` method instead. `Image.frombuffer` and `Image.fromstring` decode pixel data not raw images.

In your case you could use something like:

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(key)
text_img = Image.open(blob_reader)
.........
```

Comment: I get an error with that: `raise IOError("cannot identify image file")`

Comment: What type of image are you trying to load? Also could you try using the following `text_img = Images.open(StringIO(blob_reader.read))`.

Comment: They are just standard jpegs. I get `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` with using StringIO.

Comment: You need to use `from StringIO import StringIO`.

Comment: That's strange. I tried it in my local environment with a jpeg and it works just fine. Can you download the image and see if you can load it using just plain python + PIL. It may be that PIL does not like the image.

Comment: Ok, it worked when using the open command in plain python. [Example](http://hastebin.com/geyosapeke.py). So it looks like it's some problem with the blob_reader...?

Comment: Can you modify your example to read `img = Image.open(StringIO(open('test.jpg').read())))`. Also, did you check that your local image is the same as the one uploaded.

Comment: That works. Swapping that to `img = Image.open(StringIO(blob_reader.read()))` in my GAE app definitely does not work though... Here is the image: [Image](http://s3.uploader.nodejitsu.com.s3.amazonaws.com/1349218516317/test.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the image with PIL, not the app engine image type (another answer was off by one character: `Image`, not `Images`):

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(key)
text_img = Image.open(blob_reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw directly on the background image would be the most straightforward:

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
draw.text((0, 0), 'HELLO TEXT', font=ImageFont.load_default())
```

Comment: This gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'load'`