# Using PIL to draw image on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I have read the topic "[App Engine, PIL and overlaying text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695480/app-engine-pil-and-overlaying-text)".

The code below will show a broken image, how should I correct that?

```
class TestImg(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (800,600), (0, 0, 0, 0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_img)
        draw.text((0, 0), 'HELLO TEXT', font=ImageFont.load_default())
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
        self.response.write(draw)
```

Answer (score 6):

Building on what Tim Hoffman said, your class would look something like this:

```
import StringIO

class TestImg(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (800,600), (0, 0, 0, 0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_img)
        draw.text((0, 0), 'HELLO TEXT', font=ImageFont.load_default())

        output = StringIO.StringIO()
        text_img.save(output, format="png")
        text_layer = output.getvalue()
        output.close()

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        self.response.write(text_layer)
```

Answer (score 2):

The draw object you have can't be passed back to the browser as it is not png as such.

You need to call draw.save() and pass it a StringIO object to write the file to. (you will also need to supply a file type).  You would then`self.response.write(the_stringio.getvalue())`

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I will try again. :-)